# Can you switch which favored class bonus you take on each level up?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-advancement

As pointed out in the answer to this [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129949/how-many-bardic-performances-extra-does-a-half-elf-gain), a half-elf can choose the favored class bonus from the typical +1 hp or +1 skill point, or take any of the racial favored class bonuses offered to a half-elf. In this case, focused on bard, the options are:

> Add +1 to the bard’s total number of bardic performance rounds per day.

for Half-elf,

> Add one spell known from the bard spell list. This spell must be at least one level below the highest spell level the bard can cast.

for human, or

> Add +1 to the elf’s CMD when resisting a disarm or sunder attempt.

for elf.

My question is, could a half-elf (or anyone with multiple options like this) take a different one on each level up?

For example, could a half-elf bard take extra health for the first 2 level ups, then take an extra round of bardic performance (the Half-elf FCB) for the next level up, and then switch to taking the extra spells known (the Human FCB) for the remaining levels?

Comment: It seems the question's associating the favored class bonus with race, yet the favored class bonus is more closely associated with — um — *class.* Can this question include what classes its half-elf takes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes

A creature that has available multiple different favored class bonuses for the same class can pick a different favored class bonus each time the creature gains a level in its favored class. [Favored Class](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/#Favored_Class), in part, says

> The choice of favored class cannot be changed once the character is created, and the choice of gaining a hit point or a skill rank each time a character gains a level (including his first level) cannot be changed once made for a particular level.

The *Advanced Player's Guide* on [Racial Favored Classes](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/advancedRaces.html#racial-favored-classes)—thankfully—makes this a bit clearer, in part saying:

> The normal benefit of having a favored class is simple and effective: your character gains one extra hit point or one extra skill rank each time she gains a level in that class (or in either of two classes, if she is a half-elf).… In most cases, these benefits are gained on a level-by-level basis—your character gains the specified incremental benefit each time she gains a level. Unless otherwise noted, these benefits always stack with themselves.… In some cases this benefit may eventually hit a fixed numerical limit, after which selecting that favored class benefit has no effect. **Of course, you can still select the bonus hit point or skill rank as your favored class benefit, so there is always a reward for sticking with a favored class.**

Until the emphasized text, an assumption could be made either way, but that emphasized text seals it: if a creature has multiple options for its favored class bonus, a different (or the same) favored class bonus can be taken whenever a new level in the favored class is gained.